# How to set first page in UIPageViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

When the user is on the first page of a `UIPageViewController` and tries to go back, I simply return nil. In iOS 5 this works fine. It is causing a crash in iOS 6.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The number of view controllers provided (0) doesn't match the number required (1) for the requested transition'
```

Here is my code. When returning `contentViewController` instead of `nil`, it works fine. What should I put instead of `nil`?

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController 
  viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    contentViewController = [[ContentViewController_iPhone alloc] init];

    int currentIndex = [self.modelArray indexOfObject:[(ContentViewController_iPhone *)viewController labelContents]];

    if ((currentIndex == 0) || (currentIndex == NSNotFound)) {

        //if on the first page, can't go back
        return nil;

     }

    contentViewController.labelContents = [self.modelArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex - 1];

    return contentViewController;

}
```

Comment: Can you simply return `self` instead of `nil`?  This is conjecture on my part.

Comment: @JoshuaSmith I tried it, but I am still having the same problem. Thanks though.

Comment: Returning `nil` is exactly how Apple's “Page-Based Application” project template handles the first and last pages.  I think you have some other problem.  Set an exception breakpoint and post the full stack track of the exception.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem and found out it only happens if I change the delegates of the pageviewcontrollers gestureRecognizers to my own controller (this is done often if you want to cancel paging when a user taps certain areas on the page, **e.g. buttons**).

For me it worked to not do this reassignment for iOS 6. This is fine, as iOS handles touches a little bit different. Buttons or your own gesture recognizers on the page will work fine under iOS 6 as they have priority and will cancel paging automatically.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'll try this later. You said that buttons and my own gesture recognizers will have priority in iOS 6... is this also a change from iOS 5? Thanks.

Comment: @Jack: yes, I think it is a change (and the reason why I think the old approach isn't needed anymore an most cases)

Comment: Arrr, this was drivin' me nuts!! Look no furth'r for ye solution, mateys!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following to your code

```
if (currentIndex == 0 || (index == NSNotFound)) {

    //if on the first page, can't go back
    return nil;

 }
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. It still crashes. Returning `nil` is the issue. It doesn't like it for some reason. The if statement doesn't need to be changed.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint at nil and check whether it is even entering this block?

Comment: It is, I used a `NSLog` earlier and it outputted its contents. Again, all of this worked fine in iOS 5. It is iOS 6 which is causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of Xcode Page Based Application template provides the following code:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:(DataViewController *)viewController];
    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
    return nil;
}

index--;
return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index storyboard:viewController.storyboard];
}
```

That should do the trick :-)

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. Returning `nil` causes the issue. When I return a value other than `nil`, it works fine. How do I stop it from going to the page before the first page if nil doesn't work?